# How to convert CLOB to UTF8 in an Oracle query?

Tags: oracle, utf-8, clob

I've got a query with a CLOB field which I want to return her value in UTF8 format. The next query works fine if the field are varchar, for example, but if it is CLOB doesn't return a correct UTF8 string.

```
select convert(field, 'AL32UTF8', 'WE8ISO8859P15') from table;
```

How can I do to return a UTF8 string from a CLOB in a query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use dbms_lob package for it

for example

```
select convert(dbms_lob.substr(field,dbms_lob.getlength(field), **0**), 
              'AL32UTF8',
              'WE8ISO8859P15') 
from table;
```

**Fixed it:**

```
 select convert(dbms_lob.substr(field,dbms_lob.getlength(field)),
              'AL32UTF8',
              'WE8ISO8859P15') 
 from table;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Needle file!!! But I've got always "null" returned on field value :((((( select convert(dbms_lob.substr(c.sqlupdate, dbms_lob.getlength(c.sqlupdate), 0), 'AL32UTF8', 'WE8ISO8859P15') from sql_update c;

Comment: ups. sorry. 3 parameter substr must be 1

Comment: select convert(dbms_lob.substr(field,dbms_lob.getlength(field),1) 'AL32UTF8', 'WE8ISO8859P15') from table;

Comment: But this only works for clobs with a length less then 32k because dmbs_lob.substr returns at max 32k characters.

Comment: thanks bro, but if clob field length is greater than 4000. is that fine ?.

Answer (score 7):

Use DBMS_LOB.CONVERTTOBLOB.

From the oracle documentation:

> Oracle discourages the use of the CONVERT function in the current
>   Oracle Database release. The return value of CONVERT has a character
>   datatype, so it should be either in the database character set or in
>   the national character set, depending on the datatype. Any
>   dest_char_set that is not one of these two character sets is
>   unsupported. …

If you need a character datatype like CLOB in a character set that differs from those the database is setup with it should be converted into a BLOB.
This is where DBMS_LOB.CONVERTTOBLOB comes in.

If you need a function that returns a BLOB you have to wrap CONVERTTOBLOB into your own function.
For example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION clob_to_blob (p_clob CLOB, p_charsetname VARCHAR2)
   RETURN BLOB
AS
   l_lang_ctx      INTEGER := DBMS_LOB.default_lang_ctx;
   l_warning       INTEGER;
   l_dest_offset   NUMBER := 1;
   l_src_offset    NUMBER := 1;
   l_return        BLOB;
BEGIN
   DBMS_LOB.createtemporary (l_return, FALSE);
   DBMS_LOB.converttoblob (
      l_return,
      p_clob,
      DBMS_LOB.lobmaxsize,
      l_dest_offset,
      l_src_offset,
      CASE WHEN p_charsetname IS NOT NULL THEN NLS_CHARSET_ID (p_charsetname) ELSE DBMS_LOB.default_csid END,
      l_lang_ctx,
      l_warning);

   RETURN l_return;
END;
```

This allows queries like:

```
SELECT clob_to_blob (field, 'UTF8') FROM t;
```

To get a list of supported values for the character set name use:

```
SELECT *
  FROM v$nls_valid_values
 WHERE parameter = 'CHARACTERSET'
```